# How can i send data from Smartwatch to Flutter/companion app

Tags: flutter, xiaomi

I am trying to develop a system that consists of a smartwatch and a companion app. Companion app will be developed in Flutter. Do you know any way to send the smartwatch data(Heart rate, stress level, steps, locations, etc.) to the Flutter application?

Comment: What you are looking for is in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76464852/12555686

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the smartwatch, I think you have to tap into the native API.
Either that or you need to create a app for the smart device, see [flutter wear](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wear), that connects to the companion app

Worst case you can try and read from the health app on the phone with the health package [health](https://pub.dev/packages/health)

Comment: flutter_wear looks promising, but it presumably means implementing support for sensor data in the Android Java/KT part of the app.  https://github.com/sbis04/flutter_wear/blob/master/android/src/main/kotlin/com/souvikbiswas/flutter_wear/FlutterWearPlugin.kt

Comment: If you want to use the callbacks, you have to yes

Comment: Seems that what i am looking for is an SDK because most of the Flutter plugins are compatible with WearOS, and i am going to use XIAOMI.

Answer (score 0):

How to extract the data, completely depends on the smartwatch, but there are ways to extract it still, You can refer to this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76464852/12555686

But you have to use a bluetooth library and connect to the device. Get the list of services and characteristics and extract data accordingly. The above link explains this in detail.