# Data Transmission between Flutter App and Smart Watch

Tags: flutter

I am currently working on my graduation project, which involves predicting hypoglycemic events for diabetic patients. The project requires collecting real-time health parameters from the patient. Specifically, I aim to transfer certain parameters from the smartwatch of the patient to the Flutter application I have developed.

Even though I conducted several searches on this issue, I have found that either the vendors of the smartwatches do not make their APIs public, or if they do, they require the development of mobile applications using frameworks specifically designed for this purpose.

What I seek is a simple method for exchanging data with APIs, similar to what we commonly do. Ideally, I would like to make GET requests to the API using the user's credentials.

Could anyone here provide possible solutions and assistance ?

Comment: on the Google's wearOS?

Comment: @pskink the smart watch I have is Samsung Galaxy Watch 4, and based on searches the operating system it uses is **Wear OS 4 with One UI Watch 5**.

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer and https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/transfer-to-new-mobile

Answer (score 1):

**BLE**

Have you explored the possibility of utilizing BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy)? Does it align with the requirements of your project? I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436040/get-data-from-fitness-tracker/76464852#76464852), which gives a concise overview and references documentation on how Bluetooth devices communicate data through services.

The answer also includes an [example](https://github.com/simranss/my_fit), although it's still in development, it can serve as a valuable resource. The project utilizes the [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble) library, a crucial component that manages BLE operations for various devices. This section represents the core functionality, demonstrating the practical usage of flutter_reactive_ble for tasks such as scanning, connecting, and more.

**Api**

As you said there is no much vendors that make their APIs public.
Considering your Sony Smartwatch tag, I couldn't find a public API from their side. Alternatively, I explored the [Fitbit API](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/developer-guide/), which provides a wealth of resources covering authorization, user data permission, and numerous endpoints that could prove beneficial.

While this may not be the precise answer you were seeking, I hope it proves helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I will look more into the information you provided